# Appending markup dynamic markup elements within dynamically created divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is a twister and I am reaching out to the experts with a SOS :-)

Essentially I am reading an XML file of products and the intent is to show them as clickable records in a HTML page that would lead them to specific products. Since the number of records in the XML file can vary, I don't want to hardcode  in the HTML - there must be as many divs as the number of records. I have a Jquery that reads in the XML file through an AJAX call and loops through the file dynamically creating those divs.

The HTML should I am expecting should look like this if the dynamic creation of divs work:

```
<div id="alldiv">
  <div id="record-1234">
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <img src="http://domainname.com/images/Products/1234.png" width="25%" height="25%" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <span> Description for product 1234</span>
         </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div id="record-1235">
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <img src="http://domainname.com/images/Products/1235.png" width="25%" height="25%" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <span> Description for product 1235</span>
         </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
```

My JQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var fullpath = window.location.href;
   var categoryName = (window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]).replace(".html", '');
   var domainName = fullpath.split('/')[2];

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "productcontent.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function (xml) {

         $(xml).find('row').each(function () {
             var ListingID = $(this).find('ListingID').text();
             var Description = $(this).find('Description').text();
             $('span#description').text(Description);
             $('img#imageFile').attr('src', 'http://' + domainName + '/images/Products/' + categoryName + '/' + ListingID + '.png');

             $('<div>', {
               id: "Listing" + ListingID
             }).appendTo('#alldiv');
             $("table").appendTo("(#{id:"
               Listing "+ListingID })");

           }


         });
     },
     error: function () {
       alert("No listing exists. Please check your URL. If you believe this is in error, please call us at 760-994-4555 or email us at connect@mobikoupon.com");
     }
   });
```

The HTML that I have has the following code:

```
<table style="width:310px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px; text-align:left;">
  <tr style="background-color:#000000; font-size:15px;">
    <td style="width:25%; text-align:center;">
<img id="imageFile" src="imgFile" width="25%" height="25%" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:40%; text-align:justify;">
    <span id='description'>description</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <div id="alldiv" style="position:absolute; top:90px; left:0px; width:320px; text-align:center;"></div>
```

When I check the source, nothing seems to be happening in the HTML - the divs are not getting created as expected. Can anyone provide insight on how I can achieve this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What does $(this) in "$(xml).find('row').each" produce in console.log?

Comment: @Mark It finds the record in the XML file all right and I am getting values in ListingID, Description etc just fine.

Comment: The original html of the page as well as the input xml would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var fullpath = window.location.href;
   var categoryName = (window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]).replace(".html", '');
   var domainName = fullpath.split('/')[2];

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "productcontent.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function (xml) {
         var allDiv = $("#alldiv");

         $(xml).find('row').each(function () {
             var ListingID = $(this).find('ListingID').text();
             var Description = $(this).find('Description').text();

             var newDiv = $('<div>', {id: "record-" + ListingID}).appendTo(allDiv);
             var newRow = $("<tr>").appendTo($("<table>").appendTo(newDiv));
             $("<td>").append($("<img>", { src: 'http://' + domainName + '/images/Products/' + categoryName + '/' + ListingID + '.png', width: "25%", height: "25%"})).appendTo(newRow);
             $("<td>").append($("<span>", { text: Description})).appendTo(newRow);
           }
         });
     },
     error: function () {
       alert("No listing exists. Please check your URL. If you believe this is in error, please call us at 760-994-4555 or email us at connect@mobikoupon.com");
     }
   });
```